# Converting a Object Type Column to a numeric, string, etc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I created a data frame in python from data I pulled from `AWS`.

I'm going to work with 3 of the 67 columns and I realized the data type of these columns is object.

I want to know how to change these objects datatype to something else.

I've tried many methods but it's not working.

My data looks like this:

```
formation_tops = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/juan/Documents/revonos-ds-sandbox/formation_tops/regulatory_agency=COGCC/000000_0",
                             sep='\t', header = None, names= cols1, index_col = False, dtype='unicode')
```

Then I created a different dataframe with the 3 columns I want:

```
            formation_name log_bottom log_top
UWI                                           
05-001-05000      BENTONITE         \N    5118
05-001-05000         D SAND         \N    5211
05-001-05000      GREENHORN         \N    4908
05-001-05000         J SAND         \N    5260
05-001-05000       NIOBRARA         \N    4380
05-001-05001        CARLILE         \N    4720
05-001-05001         D SAND         \N    5131
05-001-05001      GREENHORN         \N    4821
05-001-05001         J SAND         \N    5179
05-001-05001          MOWRY         \N    5034
05-001-05001       NIOBRARA         \N    4227
```

I've tried different methods to tried to change the data type and I'm having the following errors:

```
File "pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx", line 1047, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric (pandas\_libs\lib.c:56433)

ValueError: Unable to parse string "\N" at position 0
```

Also

```
 cleaned_dataframe['log_bottom']=  cleaned_dataframe.log_bottom.str.replace('\N', '')
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: malformed \N character escape
```

I'm assuming that since there's a unicode error I should encode somehow to a readable format.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which columns to do want to change? What are you trying to convert them from and to?

Comment: Why are you passing `dtype='unicode'`? Just remove that argument to `pd.read_csv`

Comment: the first one to a string and the other two to a numeric (float or int) would be fine.

Comment: for col in width_cleaned:print (col, width_cleaned[col].dtypes)
formation_name object
log_bottom object
log_top object

Comment: I run this code and the original format is object. I took out that argument and it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert the dataframe using the function `df['column'].convert_object(convert_numeric = True)`.

This function allowed the columns to be displayed as `float64`. It will convert the `\N` as `NaN` and using the function `df.dropna()` and my dataframe is cleaned now.